# Can anyone tell me why I get segmentation error in this C code?

Tags: c

Hi I've just started programming in C and I am making a array counter but I get segmentation error when I try to run this:

```
//function to calculate the length of an array
int arr_length(char arr[]) {
  int i = 0;

  while(arr[i] != "\0") {
    i++;
  }

  return i;
}
```

Comment: `arr` is a pointer, not an array. And enable compiler warnings. Your compiler wants cry out loud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(arr[i] != "\0") {
   i++;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
char const* str = "\0";
while(arr[i] != p) {
   i++;
}
```

You are comparing a `char` with a `char*`. It evaluates to `false` most of the time. As a result, you end up accessing `arr` beyond the valid limits, which causes undefined behavior. In your case, that manifests as segmentation error.

You need to use:

```
while(arr[i] != '\0') {  // Compare with the null character
   i++;
}
```